# ¿Como enviar por medio de un formulario Variables GET?

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, variables, get

Tengo el siguiente formulario, en el cual quiero recuperar de una url las variables GET y enviarlas por medio del formulario a un CRM.

URL: https://taylorinteractivo.com?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=trafico&utm_campaign=Trafico_reserva&utm_term=Trafico_audiencia-similar&utm_content=Trafico_audiencia-similar

```html
<div action="/" class="form_p" id="form_">

<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
   <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D1a000000Z053"> 
   <input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="Internet (Web to Lead)"/>
   <input type=hidden name="utm_campaigne" value=""/>
   <input type=hidden name="utm_term" value=""/>
   <input type=hidden name="utm_content" value=""/>  

  
   <input  id="first_name" placeholder="Nombres" maxlength="80" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="last_name" placeholder="Apellidos" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="mobile" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="tel" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="email" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>    
  
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar">
  
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Por javascript puedes utilizar `new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('variable');`. En  PHP con `$_GET["variable"]`

Comment: Tienes que ser más específico sobre lo que quieres hacer, ¿qué datos quieres tomar de GET y en qué campos del formulario los vas a utilizar?, ¿Cómo obtienes los datos?

Comment: Hola Triby, yo quiero obtener los campos de la URL: utm_campaigne, utm_term, utm_content y enviarlos por un campo input del formulario (name: utm_campaigne, utm_term, utm_content )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí dejo la solución con JavaScript:
con querySt("valiable") se obtienen los valores de las varibales GET de la URL y luego se le asigna el valor a ID del input.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var utm_campaign = querySt("utm_campaign"); 
document.getElementById("Nombre_de_campa_a__c").value = utm_campaign;

var utm_term = querySt("utm_term");
document.getElementById("Grupo_de_anuncio__c").value = utm_term;

var utm_content = querySt("utm_content");
document.getElementById("Nombre_del_anuncio__c").value = utm_content;

</script>
```

```html
<div action="/" class="form_p" id="form_">

<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">       
   <input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="Internet (Web to Lead)"/>
   <input type=hidden id="Nombre_de_campa_a__c" name="Nombre_de_campa_a__c" value="" />
   <input type=hidden name="Grupo_de_anuncio__c" id="Grupo_de_anuncio__c" value=""/>
   <input type=hidden name="Nombre_del_anuncio__c" id="Nombre_del_anuncio__c" value=""/> 

  
   <input  id="first_name" placeholder="Nombres" maxlength="80" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="last_name" placeholder="Apellidos" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="mobile" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="tel" required="required"/><br>
   <input  id="email" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required="required"/><br>    
  
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar">
  
</form>
</div>
```